# Terminal not working on PhpStorm 2017.2.4

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I have this error when opening a terminal in PhpStorm:

`Can't open local terminal`

`java.io.IOException: Exec_tty error:Unknown`

I found simmilar problems on previous versions of PhpStorm fixed with the new release, but I can't find any info related to version 2017.2.4.

Has anyone got an idea why it is coming up with this error?

Comment: what shell are you using as a terminal (File | Settings | Tools | Terminal)?

Comment: :) Thank you, it was set to `powershell.exe` as I imported my settings from previous windows system. If you would like to make an answer I will accept it. It might help someone else.

Comment: Did that. Glad you've figured out a configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path to the shell (File | Settings | Tools | Terminal) should be checked to make sure a system's default one is used.